# ExecuteNonQuery () not fungsional and database failed

Tags: sql-server, mysql, visual-studio-2010

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim SumberDb As String = "Data Source=c:\users\ogieuntung\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Local Database Daftar Kontak\Local Database Daftar Kontak\DB.sdf"
    'SumberDb akan menunjukan Alamat Database 
    Dim Ogieuntung As New System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection(SumberDb)

    Dim TransaksiDb As System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeTransaction

    Ogieuntung.Open()
    TransaksiDb = Ogieuntung.BeginTransaction()
    'Setelan Koneksi "Ogieuntung".BeginTransaction berarti anda telah berhasil membuka Database
    'MsgBox("Database telah Terbuka..")

    Dim TugasDb As New System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand("inser into anggota (nama,password) values ('Nabil','1234')", Ogieuntung, TransaksiDb)

    **TugasDb.ExecuteNonQuery() 'ERROR HERE!**
    TransaksiDb.Commit()
    MsgBox("Data anda telah dimasukan ke Database!")

End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

Missing "t" on the keyword INSERT

> "***inser*** into anggota (nama,password) values ('Nabil','1234')"